# How to remove design-time package?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, install.packages

I am trying to install Asynch Pro into Delphi 2007.  I seem to have installed the wrong package (10 vs 9), and need to install a different one.  Trouble is that when I try to install the design time package, I am told that the names are already present.  How do I remove the original design-time (and run-time) packages?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Component->Install Packages` menu item. When the dialog appears, find the package you want to remove, click on it to select it, and then click the `Remove` button. You'll probably need to also delete the .dcp and .bpl files from the version you want to remove. Also, check the directories in the `Tools->Options` settings, specifically the `Environment Options->Delphi Options->Library - Win32` Library and Browsing paths, and remove any of the ones related to the Asynch Pro version you're removing.